# $.post with jQuery not returning results when done

Tags: php, jquery

```
function updateCount(text){
text = encodeURIComponent(text);
$.post("../process/countpaste.php", {text: text}).done(function( data ) {
    $( "#stats" ).empty().append($( data ));
});
}
```

On countpaste.php,

```
<?php

$text = urldecode($_POST['text']);

?>
<?=strlen($text)?> characters, <?=str_word_count($text)?> words, <?=substr_count($text, "\n")?> lines
```

For some reason, the string from the PHP page is not being placed in the #stats div. Stats exists, and this method is getting called properly.

Comment: did you echo anything from php script?

Comment: yes he does with `<?=strlen...`

Comment: Everything in the second code is the entire countpaste.php page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function updateCount(text){
    text = encodeURIComponent(text);
    $.post("../process/countpaste.php", {text: text}).done(function( data ) {
        $( "#stats" ).empty().append(   data  );
   });
}
```

not `$(data)` but just `(data)`